# Inserting a picture into body of email where file has a space in the name

Tags: html, vba, image, outlook

I've added a picture to my Outlook email using add.attachment.

The file has a space in the name i.e. "chart 1"

```
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<p><img src=""cid:chart 1.png""></p>"
```

When I try to display the picture in the the email it returns a cross where the picture should be.

How can I get the html to acknowledge the %20 in the filename?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"`) to the attachment using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`